# Gzipping using streams in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, stream

I try to zip file but I get this error: "Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read".`

```
import { createWriteStream ,createReadStream } from "fs";
import { pipeline } from "stream";
import { createGzip } from "zlib";
const filename= process.argv[2];
const gzip=createGzip();
const source=createReadStream(filename);
const destination = createWriteStream(`${filename}.gz`);

pipeline(source,gzip,destination,(err)=>{
    console.error(`Some error ocurred : ${err}`);
    process.exitCode=1;
})
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: yout code is correct, just make sure your `filename` is pointing to the file your want to compress.

Comment: If you are trying to compress a whole folder, you first need to create a "tar" out of it. Then you can compress the tar file. zlib crompressing works only on files not on whole folders. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip & https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)

Answer (score 0):

`EISDIR` stands for `"Error, Is Directory"`. This means that NPM is trying to do something to a file but it is a directory. In your case, you are trying to read a file, which is actually a directory.
There might be two reasons for this issue.

1. You may provide the path of a directory in source of reading.
   Solution-
   Check the source file path in your code by debugging or consoling the same. Which
   should be expected a file path `(eg. /YOUR/DIRECTORY/FILE_NAME.txt)`.
2. Your NPM settings may pointing to a non existing directory.
   Solution-
   Check the NPM settings on below directory path:

   `C:\Users\{User}\.npmrc`

   Open `.npmrc` and read the file which may have any file referencing path which is
   reason to your problem.
   Now, simply delete this line, and save the file.

You should get this issue resolved or have an idea to resolve by looking into these points.

[VOTE THIS ANSWER IF IT'S HELPFUL TO YOU...]

Comment: This has nothing todo with npm. The error code is from node.js and not npm. With the rest (path/file stuff) you are right. npm is "just" a package manager to manages node_modules. OP dose not even use any pacakges. He use the build in node modules and not any external resource. Please edit your answer

Comment: Thankyou @Marc for your consideration. But I wanted to let you know that this error may be relevant to NPM if there would any update in configuration (`eg. npm config set`) of npm or other node library which is being used anywhere in the application. 
So I gave him/her both the options (as a generalized answer).